# how to include static resource from a dependency in spring boot fat jar at the time of build

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application whose UI separately is built and added as a dependency to my application. Now I want to unpack the dependency and add to the resource folder of the spring boot application at the time of build so that it becomes a part of fat jar. Could someone guide me as to how this can be done with spring-boot-maven-plugin.

note: the project is using maven for build

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>nflow-explorer</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>io.nflow</includeGroupIds>
                        <includeArtifactIds>nflow-explorer</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/resources/main/static/explorer
                            <!-- or: ${project.basedir}/wherever/you/want/it -->
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to unpack the JAR.

Simply use the Maven Resource Plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html

You can specify directories to include like this:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: how will that become a part of the fat jar. ??? I tried this although the target folder seems to have the static resource however the fat jar does not include that.

Comment: added the build section of the pom t

Comment: I can't see that you are using the resource plugin in your pom.xml but you said you've tried that

Comment: ok i figured it out . I did the copying of external dependency in the validate phase